# What is this code doing&

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
typedef unsigned long long  ul64;
double m[10] = { 65.45433, 45435.0054, 232543535.9, 0.00043543, 99.99999, 5345434.000, 754354.6, 80008.243, 0.9, 10.01 };
union foo
{
    char cs[8];
    double x;
    ul64 a;
    foo(std::string s) { for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) cs[i] = s[i];}
    foo(double y) :x(y){}
    foo(ul64 b) :a(b){}
};
int main()
{
    foo bar(0xe8e711395e65686d);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        bar.x *= m[i];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        std::cout << bar.cs[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have this code for my exam, but i don't know what is is doing. Help me please! I only know that it has some errors and display something.

Comment: Do you know what a union is?

Comment: This code is cruel, and depends on what processor it's run on

Comment: One thing it's doing is undefined behavior since it's reading array m from 1 to 10.

Comment: That is just really bad code.  Really bad code.

Comment: On my machine it produces "`error: call of overloaded 'foo(long unsigned int)' is ambiguous`".  If I fix that, it prints "`��`" http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa34fa0b744924ea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is just overwhelming you.

Just start with the first line of main: What does

```
    foo bar(0xe8e711395e65686d);
```

do? It creates a variable named bar, which has type foo, and a constructor is called with a parameter 0xe8e711395e65686d. So what does this do?

Reading the comment of Mooing Duck: What is it intended to do, and how do you fix it so that it will do what it is intended to do?

You have two for-loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
```

Both contain the same beginner's mistake. What is the mistake? Fix it.

At last in the output loop, you need to understand what a union is. The code is weird, but you should still be able to explain what it does.